# Microsoft.Owin.Security.Oauth Bearer Token Authorization Interception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I am in the process of implementing OAuth 2 on a web API with `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Oauth`.

I would like to keep the bearer token small and keep private data out of it. To do this, I'd like to store a session ID in it and then fill out the `ClaimsIdentity` programmatically once the session ID has been received and processed. This would also give me greater flexibility related to how logging out, role changes, and other things can be handled.

This should be a matter of intercepting the right event and adding a delegate. However, I can't find an event that gets fired on my authorization provider, a  subclass of `"OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider"`. I thought that `"AuthorizeEndpoint"` would do it, but it does NOT get fired for API methods decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute, even though these methods clearly get checked for a valid bearer token. When I overrode `"MatchEndpoint"`, all I found is that a call to a method that was decorated with [Authorize] showed up with `"IsAuthorizeEndpoint"` and `"IsTokenEndpoint"` both set to false. The latter makes sense to me, the former does not.

I am very confused. Can somebody who knows this library tell me what's going on and what I need to do to accomplish this seemingly simple idea?

Comment: Looks potentially similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675844/adding-extra-details-to-a-webapi-bearer-token ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be conflating resources marked with the AuthorizeAttribute with the OWIN Authorize endpoint. The AuthorizeEndpoint and TokenEndpoint are setup in the OWIN configuration as receivers for their respective authentication types. The Authorize Endpoint is used for web-base, user-agent authentication and is where you would expect a browser to be redirected should they be unauthorized to access a resource. The token endpoint is used instead for username-password token authentication and refreshing, and is the one you want. Assuming you are assigning both of these within your OWIN startup configuration, the event you may be looking to overload for `OnValidateTokenRequest` to ensure that your customizations to the token do not cause it to be invalid once the client tries to utilize it again. You would want to do your actual modifications to the token at the `OnTokenEndpoint` event.